# Owin OpenIdConnect RC1 (nightly)

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

I have a problem installing the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect RC1 nuget package from the nightly feed.

This is the ASP.Net nightly builds nuget feed channel:
http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/

`Unable to resolve dependency 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (≥ 4.0.0-Beta2-10617-1039)'.`

Answer (score 1):

Include the feed http://www.myget.org/F/azureadwebstacknightly/ to download the missing packages. Hope this solves it for you